# Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 Array 3D

Tags: java, arrays

I am using a 3D array int the below code i am getting array index out of bound error below is the code for the same:-

```java
package array2d;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array3 {

    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        Scanner vee= new Scanner(System.in);
        int penilaian[][][];
        int mahasiswa[];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Class" + (i + 1) + " : ");
            int mhs = vee.nextInt();

            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
            mahasiswa = new int[mhs];

            penilaian = new int[i][mahasiswa.length][3];

            for (int j = 0; j < mahasiswa.length; j++) {
                System.out.print("Score Mid Test" + (i + 1) + " Ke -" + (j + 1) + " :");
                penilaian[i][j][0] = vee.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Score Test" + (i + 1) + " Ke -" + (j + 1) + " :");
                penilaian[i][j][1] = vee.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Score Project" + (i + 1) + " Ke -" + (j + 1) + " :");
                penilaian[i][j][2] = vee.nextInt();
                System.out.println("=======================================================================");

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Getting the below error:-

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
>       at array2d.TugasArray3.main(TugasArray3.java:27)
>   Score Mid Test1 Ke -1

Comment: what is the input and what output you are expecting add all details

Comment: That's quite expected: you can't access index 0 of an array which doesn't have any element. What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you   declare a three-dimensional (3d) array  `penilaian = new int[i][mahasiswa.length][3];` when `i=0`  the size of first element is `0` therfore you cant assign any value to this array